# Request 'GET /sw.js' doesn't match 'POST /login Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am running Spring Boot v2.3.2.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.8.RELEASE and after a successful login I get `Request 'GET /sw.js' doesn't match 'POST /login`. This happens in Chrome but not in Firefox.

This is my security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private LdapAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    /**
     * Defines the web based security configuration.
     *
     * @param   http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
     * @throws  Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login") //custom login page
                    .permitAll(); // permit everyone the /login page

    }

    /**
     * Sets a custom authentication provider.
     *
     * @param   auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
     * @throws  Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }
```

My home controller is:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Principal principal) throws IsimConnectionException {
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) principal;


        if ((authentication.getPrincipal() != null) && (authentication.isAuthenticated())) {
```

...
My login controller is:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Here is my stack:

```
2021-09-27 15:10:12,119 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository: Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ac138ad5: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ac138ad5: Principal: xxx; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 2B1ED69302276F95FB5CB97E87F7CF64; Not granted any authorities'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher: Request 'GET /error' doesn't match 'POST /login'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache: saved request doesn't match
2021-09-27 15:10:12,120 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,121 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,121 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter: SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ac138ad5: Principal: asusti; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 2B1ED69302276F95FB5CB97E87F7CF64; Not granted any authorities'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,121 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,121 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,121 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2021-09-27 15:10:12,122 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain: /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2021-09-27 15:10:12,123 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter: Chain processed normally
2021-09-27 15:10:12,123 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter: SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Can you please suggest what is missing in my configuration?

**Update:**
This is the network screenshot when the error appears from Chrome:
[image: screenshot]

My login.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Login page </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Please Login</legend>
            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">
                Invalid username and password.
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error sw.js line no 18 that is throwing 404 error. work-box-core.. not found:
[image]

Comment: add specific js (/sw.js) in web configure ignore requests. Eg. `.antMatchers("/sw.js").permitAll()`

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh the "no mapping found" is gone. Do you maybe know why that happens in chrome and not in firefox?

Comment: Can you check network tab in chrome share the screenshot

Comment: I did @Rajesh in my initial question.

Comment: can you check your sw.js line no 18 it's throwing 404 error. work-box-core.. not found

Comment: Hi @Rajesh. I updated the initial question of mine with the screenshot of the error sw.js line no 18. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Try to find out where you use work-box-core internally it's trying to access workbox-core.dev.js.map resource and it's showing 404 error

Comment: I have no idea. I am running the embedded tomcat with intelliJ. Could that be a reason?